# Sorting with Nulls Last

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> SortByRegion(IEnumerable<Customer> customerList)
{
    return customerList.OrderBy(x => x.Region).ThenBy(x => x.ContactName);
}
```

It needs to `Orderby` `Region`, then by `ContactName`. But have the Null `Regions` at the bottom. I have tried the following:

```
customerList.OrderBy(x => x.Region != null).ThenBy(x => x.ContactName);
```

But id did not work. Been googling for a while. Cant seem to find it.

Comment: Have you tried using `OrderByDescending` on `x.Region` ?

Comment: What about this:

    `OrderBy(x => x.Region != null ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: Salah's answer works, but you'll also still need to sort by region. ``OrderBy(x => x.Region == null ? 1 : 0).ThenBy(x => x.Region).ThenBy(x => x.ContactName)``.

Comment: May be you are looking for `customerList.OrderBy(x => x.Region ?? string.empty).ThenBy(x => x.ContactName);`

Comment: Hi, if you feel an answer helped you to solve your issue, please don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
OrderBy(x => x.Region != null ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: Perhaps `OrderBy(x => x.Region ?? string.empty)` could be better option.

Comment: @MKR Right, that could be also an interesting alternative.

Comment: I can't intuitively understand why this code sorts nulls last. Could you explain it and provide a more self-documenting version?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since `false < true` for `null` last you can put

```
 OrderBy(x => x.Region == null)
```